# Read out the value of the related discriminator map

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an `Order` entity, what has a property called `$name`. This property is an entity called `Heading` and has a one to one relation to the order table.

Also, this heading has a discrimiatormap, here are the annotation:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Heading")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
*     "simple"="SimpleName",
*     "separated"="SeparatedName",
*     "company"="CompanyName"
* })
*/
```

Foreign keys are set properly.

What I want to achieve, to get the name of the user.

I am trying to get a column, called fullName with the name of user.

This how I try:

```
$queryBuilder->leftJoin(
        'e.name',
        'h',
    );

    $queryBuilder->addSelect('
    (
        CASE
            WHEN h INSTANCE OF '.SimpleName::class.' THEN h.name
            WHEN h INSTANCE OF '.CompanyName::class.' THEN h.company
            WHEN h INSTANCE OF '.SeparatedName::class." THEN CONCAT(h.first_name, ' ', h.last_name)
            ELSE ''
        END
     )
         AS fullName
    ");
```

It fails, it says, `Utils\\Model\\Heading\\Heading has no field or association named name`.

I've tried `THEN h.SimpleName`, but I also get no field for SimpleName.

If I just using a string there like `ssss`, `ccccc`, `spspsps`, then it's cool, I am getting the result, so the `CASE WHEN ELSE` is works.

How can I reference to those fields? What should I wrote after the `THEN` in the 3 cases?

`CompanyName`, `SimpleName` and `SeparatedName` are extends the `Heading` class.

Here is the CompanyName class for example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CompanyName extends Heading
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private ?string $companyName = null;

    public static function create(?string $companyName = null): self
    {
        $object = new self();
        $object->companyName = $companyName;

        return $object;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->companyName ?? '';
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return 'company';
    }

    public function getCompanyName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->companyName;
    }

    public function setCompanyName(?string $companyName): self
    {
        $this->companyName = $companyName;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've changed the `h` to `orderHeading`, and here is the solution.

```
protected function createQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder
{
    $queryBuilder = parent::createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(
        'e.name',
        'orderHeading'
    );
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(SeparatedName::class, 'separatedName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = separatedName.id')
    ->leftJoin(SimpleName::class, 'simpleName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = simpleName.id')
    ->leftJoin(CompanyName::class, 'companyName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = companyName.id');

    $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('groupBy');
    $queryBuilder->addGroupBy('e');

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

.....

```
protected function createCountQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder
{
    $queryBuilder = parent::createCountQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(
        'e.name',
        'orderHeading'
    );
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(SeparatedName::class, 'separatedName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = separatedName.id')
    ->leftJoin(SimpleName::class, 'simpleName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = simpleName.id')
    ->leftJoin(CompanyName::class, 'companyName', Join::WITH, 'orderHeading.id = companyName.id');

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

and after that you can reference to these columns as

```
    $propertyMap['fullName'] = new ColumnSqlDescriptor('
        CASE
            WHEN orderHeading INSTANCE OF '.SimpleName::class.' THEN simpleName.name
            WHEN orderHeading INSTANCE OF '.CompanyName::class.' THEN companyName.companyName
            WHEN orderHeading INSTANCE OF '.SeparatedName::class." THEN CONCAT(separatedName.firstName, ' ', separatedName.lastName)
            ELSE 'NA'
        END
    ");
```